# Is automatic success guaranteed when Aiding Another with a high skill?

Tags: dnd-4e, skills

In my campaign, we've used the old mechanics for Aid Another up until now: roll 10 or more to assist with a +2, if you roll under you simple fail to assist.
I recently became aware of the errataed Aid Another, which looks like this:

> The assisting creature makes a skill check or an ability check against
>   a DC equal to 10 + one-half its level.

My players are currently level 18, which means their Aid Another DC is 19. A lot of the players have a 17 or higher in a few skills, though. For example, the ardent has 24 in diplomacy, 18 in endurance and 17 in insight - does this mean automatic success is guaranteed when she assists with those skills (barring a 1, which we assume is always automatic failure)?

Comment: Yes, they'll auto-succeed, but the people who can auto-succeed are the ones who should be *receiving* help via Aid Another, not *giving* help via Aid Another.

Comment: No harm, no foul! Tagging issues are very much inside baseball anyway. It's [currently](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2871/time-to-burninate-the-mechanics-tag) being [discussed](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1587/is-the-mechanics-tag-useful-or-a-problem); feel free to chime in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Yes, for skills, it’s an automatic success, even on a Nat-1

You succeed on a skill check every time your roll plus your bonus meets or exceeds the DC. If your bonus is as large or larger than the DC, then there is no possible roll that results in you failing to meet the DC, and thus you automatically succeed.

The auto-failure on a natural-1 rule does not apply to skill checks (nor does the auto-success on a nat-20 rule).

---

As an important aside, there are a lot of very good reasons for natural-1 not applying to skill checks, and it is strongly recommended that you not houserule that particular feature.

Skills are supposed to be things you are reasonably good at, particularly when you’re trained and high level. A 5% chance of failure is *much* too high a rate for the kinds of activities we’re usually talking about. Worse, in some cases, like jumping, there is no particular set DC: you just go as far as you can based on what you roll. What does an “automatic success” even *mean* in that case? Does that mean I have a 5% chance of successfully jumping to the moon?

Even in less silly cases, training is supposed to represent a deep internalization of the skill. At appropriate levels of training, you are intended to be able to accomplish certain tasks – indicated by having a DC low enough that they can be hit automatically – as easily as the average person can sit down in a chair. People do, on rare occasions, mess up sitting in a chair, particularly in poor conditions (poorly-balanced chair, person is inebriated, whatever), but it happens *way* less frequently than 5% of the time, *even* in poor conditions. The d20 simply doesn’t have the granularity to measure that. Changing this is a severe nerf to the skill-based folks in the party, and causes some pretty serious problems.

Comment: I would never have anyone roll to see if they could jump over the moon. If it's impossible, it's impossible. And the other way around, if it's so easy that there is no chance of failure, I don't make the players roll for it. So I feel comfortable having auto success and auto failure on skill checks.

Comment: @Ravn The game says you are *supposed* to automatically succeed when you are trained. For a trained person, making that check is as easy as successfully sitting down in a chair is for us. Sure, once in a *long* while, they might flub it (particularly in poor conditions), but almost always this is a thing they can do. The d20 does not have enough granularity to model this. You are pretty seriously nerfing your skill-based characters with this houserule.

Comment: So a player trained in a skill should never have to roll for it?

Comment: @Ravn If they have a bonus high enough/they're aiming for a low enough DC? Yes. That is how the game works.

Comment: I did an example edit that doesn't reduce the tangent, but marks it clearly as an "I'm going to go off on a tangent now, but dammit this is important" thing. By separating it, it prevents confusion of the "but that's not what I was talking about… maybe they misunderstood my question?" kind, and calling it out as a tangent makes it more prominent, as a bonus.

Comment: @KRyan But won't that obviate the point of skill checks altogether once the group reaches a certain level? If the group faces an arcane lock, the wizard automatically disables it. If the group needs to identify a poison, the shaman automatically does so. If the groups needs to move a heavy boulder, the fighter automatically does so. It seems to me that if there's no chance of failure, the skill-part of the game ceases to be a challenge?

Comment: @Ravn The intent is that as the players level, they become greater and greater fantasy heroes: incredibly powerful, able to accomplish on a whim tasks literally impossible for the average person. They go from just another band of adventurers, struggling to *assist* in handling a town's local bandit problem, to people who can speak on even footing with heads of state, and then with entire worlds, and then with gods and ancient evils. When and where each happens depends on setting, but by Epic levels, you're usually approaching that last one.

Comment: @Ravn So no, the same challenges they used to face no longer challenge them in any way. But they should have *new* challenges, and these with higher DCs that even they have to roll for. It's important to the game that you demonstrate to the PCs how far they have come: let them trivially accomplish that which they struggled to achieve in the past. And then give them something that they'll struggle to achieve even now.